# Can't understand C++11 template function parameter deduction

Tags: c++, c++11, templates, overloading

```
template <int T> struct int2type{};

template<int I>
void func( int2type<I> )
{
     printf("int_val: %i\n", I);
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    func( int2type<10>() ); 
}
```

Of course it prints 10.

I have some basic idea of how templates and type deduction works, but i can't understand this code. What is the magic behind `I`? How we know `I` from `int2type` instance passed to `func`?

Comment: I don't see what's magical about this. The compiler expects the argument to be `int2type<I>` for some `I`. You pass in an argument of type `int2type<10>`. The compiler compares them and sees that `I` must be `10` in order for the two types to be identical.

Comment: Ohh yes! Now I see how it works. Thank You!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Template argument deduction is covered by section [temp.deduct.call] of the C++14 Standard. It is too big to reproduce in full, but the gist is that the compiler will compare the argument type `int2type<10>` with the parameter type `int2type<I>` and try to find a value for `I` that makes both of those the same.

In [temp.deduct.type]/9 and /17 it is specified that the parameter `class-template-name<i>`, where `i` is a non-type template parameter, is matched by the argument `class-template-name<n>` where `n` is an argument of the same type.